# Translation correctness?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it a correct translation for writing that somebody is currently studying a German course?

> Hiermit wird bestätigt, dass Herr Green derzeit den Deutschkurs Niveau A 1.2 studiert.

Thank You!

Comment: Is there anything specific about the translation that causes your concern?

Comment: The translation itself, the sequence of words.

Comment: @Antarctica -- I think what Arsak was getting ar was that this site prefers specific questions rather than "please translate this" or "please check my work". The idea is that the collection of questions and answers should serve as a reference for other people, and a "please check" request is unlikely to provide useful, searchable information that others can use. It looks like this question will be closed soon and that's the reason.

Answer (score 1):

I would write "besucht" and not "studiert". Because you can't study ("studieren") a german course, you rather attend ("besuchen") a german course. If you mean *study german* ("Deutsch studieren"), it would be *study german philology* ("Germanistik studieren") at the university.

> "Hiermit wird bestätigt, dass Herr Green derzeit den Deutschkurs Niveau A 1.2 **besucht**."

Answer (score 1):

More suggestions:

- Hiermit wird bestätigt, dass Herr Green derzeit am Deutschkurs Niveau A 1.2 teilnimmt.
- Hiermit wird Herrn Green die Teilnahme am Deutschkurs Niveau A 1.2 bestätigt.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you **study** a language, but you **attend** a course.

Now, it depends on what kind of information *Niveau A 1.2* is. If it is indeed the name of the course and you want to refer to it, you can write:

> - […] dass Herr Green derzeit *den Deutschkurs Niveau A 1.2* **besucht**.
> - […] dass Herr Green derzeit *am Deutschkurs Niveau A 1.2* **teilnimmt**.

If, however, it is only additional information, you can write something like

> - […] dass Herr Green derzeit *unseren Deutschkurs (Niveau A 1.2)* **besucht**.
> - […] dass Herr Green derzeit *unseren Deutschkurs auf Niveau A 1.2* **besucht**.
>
>   …
> - […] dass Herr Green derzeit *Deutsch (Niveau A 1.2)* **studiert**.
> - […] dass Herr Green derzeit *Deutsch auf Niveau A 1.2* **studiert**.

As often, there are even more possibilites, but the ones above should suffice for the moment.

Comment: Vorschlag: Nimm "besucht" statt "belegt".